# Insert multiple elements into array with splice method

Tags: javascript, splice

I have a problem I'm trying to solve. I am trying to insert a space where ever there is a instance of a capital letter. The problem is that the space is pushed into the correct index but for all other instances where a capital letter appears, it doesn't apply that space. I have researched extensively about the splice methods but could not figure out a solution to my problem. Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
function solution(string) {
  
  let splitStr = [...string];
  
  
  for(let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    
    if(!splitStr[i].toUpperCase()) return
    
    if(splitStr[i] === splitStr[i].toUpperCase()) {
        let indexOfCapLetter = splitStr.indexOf(splitStr[i].toUpperCase());
        splitStr.splice(indexOfCapLetter, 0, ' ' );
        
        return splitStr
      }
    
  }
  
 
}
```

Comment: Because when `splitStr[i] === splitStr[i].toUpperCase()` you insert a space then return.

Comment: Your logic is also broken. Inserting a space increments the index of following letters, so if you insert a space at 4, the letter is moved to 5 so on the next iteration you test the same letter again, insert another space, etc. *ad infinitum* (or until you get a stack overflow). So when you insert a space, do an extra increment of *i* (or loop from splitStr.length to zero or right to left, not zero to splitStr.length or left to right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue is that you're returning the array inside your  if statement within the loop. This escapes the function after the first capital letter. But after that there's another issue.

Whenever you add a new element to the array, the characters after it are moved to a higher index.

To counter this you can loop through the array backwards so the affected elements are always ones you've already parsed:

```js
function solution(string) {
  
  let splitStr = [...string];
  
  
  for(let i = splitStr.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    
    if(splitStr[i] === splitStr[i].toUpperCase()) {
        splitStr.splice(i, 0, ' ' );
      }
  }
  
  return splitStr.join('');
}

console.log(solution('HelloWorldLongString'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand everything you said! But I don want to go over the part about the decrement. Wouldn't that cause the same problem because we are still moving the indexes.

Comment: @Alanaj When we add or remove an element at `i` we are only affecting indexes after `i`, and because we're moving backwards through the array the future iterations only care about index's before `i`,  so won't cause any problems.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the explanation. It will take a minute to digest. Have a good week!